lower bound on the eigenvalues of a particular PD matrix
Consider the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 &... & A_m\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with $m > n$. Assume $A$ has full rank. Then let $D = diag \{ \lambda_1, ..., \lambda_m\}$ where $\lambda_k > 0$. I want a lower bound on the eigenvalues of
$$
 M = A \cdot D \cdot A^T
$$
I know that they are all greater than zero and $M$ is symmetric hence it is positively defined. Can a larger than zero lower bound be given?

using the Rayleigh quotient
$
x^T M x = x^T A D A^T x \geq \lambda_{\min}(D) x^T A A^T x.
$
This implies
$\lambda_{\min}(M) \geq \lambda_{\min}(D) \lambda_{\min}(A A^T)$.
